# add compile definitions to sibling cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following structure:

```
Foo/
├─ Executable/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ Module_Library/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

Foo/CMakeLists.txt decides whether `Module_Library` gets compiled via `option()`
If `Module_Library`  gets compiled, I want to set a compiler definition in `Executable`.
Is that possible?

I currently use this in Module_Library/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(Executable IMPORTED)
target_compile_definitions(Executable INTERFACE MODULE_FILE=\"LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME\")
```

But it does not work, i.e. the compiler definition is not there when compiling Executable

Comment: Why using `IMPORTED` ? if your executable is a precompiled binary there is no compilation step so your compile definition is useless...

Comment: Why are you definining any property with `INTERFACE` visibility on an ***executable*** target? Executables cannot be linked to other targets via `target_link_libraries` making this pointless.

Comment: @Mizux what does "precompiled" mean in this case? It's an executable I build alongside with the module

Comment: @Raildex `IMPORTED` targets are not built by your solution, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html#imported-executables . This target doesn't seem to serve any purpose in this case. If you want targets linking `Module_Library` to have the compile definition applied to them, use `target_compile_definitions(Module_Library INTERFACE ...)`.

Comment: Alternatively the decision should to add the compile definition should be made close to the logic linking `Module_Library` to your real executable target in `Executable`: `if (LINK_MODULE_LIB) target_link_libraries(Executable PRIVATE Module_Library) target_compile_definitins(Executable PRIVATE MODULE_FILE=\"LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME\")`

Comment: @fabian `Module_Library` is a `MODULE` library. It is not linked against `Executable`.

Comment: @fabian - executable targets _can_ be linked that way if `ENABLE_EXPORTS` is set on them. Typically used for plug-in stuff. Never tried it on an imported target though